# Looking for a program/script to collect sentences from news articles

Tags: scripting

So I'm currently working on a research paper on media bias (or lack thereof) towards 2020 presidential candidates.

For this, I'm looking for a way to make a huge database of sentences that mention these politicians by name or (if possible) with a pronoun. Right now I'd like to only focus on 5-7 of the biggest American news outlets (WaPo, NYT, FOX, etc.).

I want to collect all of these sentences into an Excel sheet, including a timestamp of when the article was released and a link to the article itself. I actually don't know if that's feasible or whether such program/script exists or not.

Do you think there's a way to solve this, does it already exist, and if not, can a rookie programmer write a script for this?

Thank you for all your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably just need to create your own web scraper. You could have a Set of names that you're looking for, and if the name exists on the page then you can have some heuristics to get the sentence it's in. You'll probably have to have some specific stuff for getting the timestamp from the article. I'd say it wouldn't be too bad since you're targeting only a few news outlets, but probably a bit challenging for a rookie programmer.

Also, I recommend checking out something like https://www.webscraper.io/